# QGIS count item

Tags: qgis, count

I have the following table filled out in QGIS.
How do I count each fruit present in the 'execucao01' column, obtaining the following result?
BANANA = 10
MACA = 13
PERA = 12
LARANJA = 11

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To count the numbers of "BANANA", you can use this expression:

```
count("execucao01", 
      filter:=(array_contains(
                   string_to_array(
                        substr("execucao01", 2,-1)), 
               '"BANANA"'))= true)
```

1. `substr("execucao01", 2,-1)` will remove leading and tailing braces `{}` before turning the string into an array by `string_to_array()` command.
2. `array_contains(+++++, '"BANANA"')` determins if the said array contains `"BANANA"`. It then acts as an filter (checks if it returns `true`) to be included in the `count()`.

Next, to count "MACA", the same expression will be used by replacing "BANANA" by "MACA".

[image]

A quick test on your first three rows is seen below.

[image]

Repeat the process for other items.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Now I’m going to try to improve it, by searching the list of fruits on another table and making the total.

Comment: I tried, but I couldn't. I changed my question to put the results in another table with the list of fruits and their totals. It's possible?

Comment: @Denilson What part of your workflow did not work, may I ask?

Comment: The solution you presented worked very well, but it puts the result in the original table, creating new columns.
I tried but I couldn't put the results in a new table where I have 2 fields, 'fruit' name and 'total' (I changed my question to include the example of that table). I tried to use the aggregation function.

count (aggregate (layer: = 'TABLE_A', aggregate: = 'concatenate', expression: = "execucao01"),
filter: = (array_contains (string_to_array (substr (aggregate (layer: = 'TABLE_A', aggregate: = 'concatenate', expression: = "execucao01"), 2, -1)), '"FRUIT"')) = true )

Comment: @Denilson Unfortunately I cannot offer a solution which does it in one action. I would suggest creating a virtual layer to turn the output of my answer into the table you want (like a pivot table in Excel).

Comment: I think this is the way. I tried to create using virtual field on the fruit table.

Comment: @Denilson Great. Then, would you open a new question for that part? I will try to answer it asap.