# Counting items in another table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, fields-attributes, count, virtual-field

I have two tables, the table 'fruit' contains a list of fruits (see figure 01).

[image]

The 'municipality' table shows in the column `"execucao01"` which fruits exist in each municipality (see figure 02).

[image]

I would like to create a virtual field in the 'fruit' table to obtain the total existence of each type of fruit in the 'municipality' table.

I tried to use the aggregation function.

```
count(
    aggregate(layer:='municipality',
    aggregate:='concatenate',
    expression:="execucao01"),
    filter:=(
        array_contains(
            string_to_array(
                substr(
                    aggregate(layer:='municipality',
                    aggregate:='concatenate',
                    expression: = "execucao01"), 2, -1)
                ),
            ' "FRUIT" ')
        ) = true
    )
```

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

This is a a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) approach (not a virtual field solution), but hopefully you get what you have aimed.

Assuming you already have a table below, following the answer to [your earlier question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387142/qgis-count-item).

[image]

Then I propose to turn the `data` table into the intended format (so-called 'pivot table') by:

1. From the menu, select `Layer > Create Layer > New Virtual Layer`
2. **Import** the layer (`data` layer in this example).
3. Enter a query as described below.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM(
      SELECT 'BANANA'  AS FRUIT, Max(BANANA)  AS TOTAL FROM data
UNION SELECT 'MACA'    AS FRUIT, Max(MACA)    AS TOTAL FROM data
UNION SELECT 'PERA'    AS FRUIT, Max(PERA)    AS TOTAL FROM data
UNION SELECT 'LARANJA' AS FRUIT, Max(LARANJA) AS TOTAL FROM data
)
```

[image]

Then you will get a new `virtual_layer` whose attribute table will show the summary.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more or less simple expression that does the job (explanation as comment in expression), assuming your `execucao01` field is a string field:

```sql
array_length(
    array_filter(
        string_to_array(
            array_to_string(
                aggregate('municipality','array_agg',regexp_replace("execucao01",'[{}"]','')) -- aggregate all values from the destination layer into one single array; remove {, } and " signs from the values
            ,',') -- array_to_string: turn the array into a string, as it has the wrong format
        ,',') -- string_to_array: create a "real" array from the string
    ,@element = "FRUIT") -- array_filter: only keep the lookup-fruit in the current array
) -- array_length: count number of fruits
```

[image]